# unix expr: syntax error

Tags: unix, expr

Why is the following expression giving me a expr: syntax error?

```
pingval=`expr ping6 -c 1 "$url"`
```

Basically I want to use the value returned by the above expression in another expression e.g.

```
var=$($pingval|tail -1 ....
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using `expr` at all? It's generally used for simple maths / string functions.

You can assign the result (stdout) of that expression just using the backticks, or in a more modern way directly with:

```
pingval=$(ping6 -c1 "$url" | tail -1)
```

If you did want to build the shell expression before using, try something like:

```
cmd="ping6 -c 1 '$url' | tail -1"
echo cmd | sh
```

Comment: Basically I want to use pingval in multiple expressions. Having used the above method I keep getting an error PING: Command not found?

Comment: Which of the two methods caused that? And what operating system is this on?

Comment: using a vi editor in unix. The error comes in the expression in which I try and use the value given pingval i.e. 
    cmd=$($pingval| tail -1| awk '{print $4}')

Comment: This works for me: `var=$(ping6 -c 1 "$url" | tail -1 | awk '{print $4}')"`, giving something like `0.025/0.025/0.025/0.000`

Comment: I appreciate that, the same method works for me. The only issue is that I want to use the value given by pingval multiple times without having to re-run the ping expression.

Comment: That's fine - using `$(...)` evaluates the expression once only. The value `$var` or `$pingval` is just a string after that

Comment: So why do you think: 
`pingval=$(ping6 -c 1 "$url")`
`var=$($pingval| tail -1| awk '{print $4}')`
is giving me the error?

Comment: The clue's in the name there: `pingval` is a (string) _value_, but you're trying to _execute_ it in the second bit. Either call it `pingcmd` and *don't* execute with `$(...)` (i.e. second example in my answer), or use `echo` in your second statement: `var=$(echo $pingval | tail -1 | awk '{print $4}')`

Comment: @user3352349 If the answer helped, please mark the question as complete (or upvote) or if not, explain why - thanks.